# django + mysql text field format with breakline

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I have a `text` field in my MySQL table. I want to format all new lines with the `<br>` or some sort of formatting for the template. Is there anything built into the framework for this? I tried to read into the following page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs

But seems like that page won't work for this? Is there another documentation I can refer to? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need the [`linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) template filter.

Normally, you would use it in the template:

```
{{ instance.fieldname|linebreaksbr }}
```

However, it's possible to import it and use it in your view as well:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaksbr
text_with_br = linebreaksbr(instance.fieldname)
```

The advantage of using `linebreaksbr` instead of writing your own snippet, is that the linebreaksbr takes care of [autoescaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping) for you.

Comment: I never heard of that template tag. But I like it better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do it the following way: `"<br />".join(word.split("\n"))`. Not sure if that's the best way...still digging into it. It certainly works though!

Comment: Django's `linebreaksbr` uses `replace`, but using `split` and `join` is fine as well. The main advantage of using the built in linebreaksbr instead of your own snippet, is that the `linebreaksbr` takes care of autoescaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill for you depending on your use case,  but I use [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) in my admin area to add rich text editing fields to charfields that will be used in templates.  This saves a html string in the database and in your template you can just use:

```
{{ model.field|safe }}
```

to output it without losing the html formatting. It's quite easy to set up.